# How should I install Azure Storage Explorer on Linux Mint 18.3?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am new to MS-Azure. I want to know how can I install Azure Storage Explorer on my Linux Mint-18.3 PC. What are the pre-requisites and what should I do with the connection string provided to me by the trainer?

Comment: Maybe start with [the setup instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=linux)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Apparently this is not true anymore. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=linux) claims storage emulator works on Ubuntu. But you would have to port it to Mint :)

You can also try [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-storage-emulator/) docker image, but its windows based.

```
docker pull microsoft/azure-storage-emulator
```

You can also try [Azurite](https://github.com/azure/azurite).
[image]

Comment: As mint is based on Debian/Ubuntu the effort should be limited.